# How to clean a big artificial plant without spending hours on it?

Tags: cleaning

Paintbrush will take forever (1m50 plant with tons of leaves). I put it under the shower and that removed only 50% of the dust - which is more than just laying on the leaves's surface. Any better idea?

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into this before. The problem is that the dust still on the plant is adhered with oils most likely. My suggestion is a degreaser like dish soap mixed in water and sprayed onto it, let sit a while, and then rinsed off.

If the leaves are not welded into place and can be pulled off, make sure you stopper the tub (presuming you are using a tub/shower) so loosened leaves do not get lost down the drain.

Comment: mixing dishwasher machine detergent (liquid, powder, or pods) with water makes a powerful and cheap clean-rinsing degreaser. Seems to be more powerful than dawn and rinses off a lot easier and w/o building up suds.